# Hide table header if page has no rows with pagination (Flying Saucer)

Tags: html, css, itext, flying-saucer

Currently I have a dynamic table that is printed on multiple pages, and have a repeated header using Flying Saucer pagination.
The problem I am facing is if the table is too low at the bottom of the page, it just prints the table header and does not have any rows under it.

I am wondering how I can hide the header if there are no rows on the same page. The entire page is dynamic, so I cannot hardcode the table to go to the next page as I do not know how low the table will be.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```
<!-- lots of dynamic data, spans across multiple pages -->
<table>
 <thead>
  <th>
   myheader
  </th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    ~lots of data, rows  epeated multiple times dynamically
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add a class in the table, if there are no rows?